# What is the benefit of using raw_native_types?

Tags: com, atl

I've encountered the raw_native_types in a tlb import statement and I'm unclear of what the benefit of this attribute is.  I've read the MSDN description for this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#_predir_raw_native_types) but it hasn't helped clearing it up for me.  Can someone help explain it to me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intention defines the benefit.  If one really doesn't want to use `_bstr_t` or `_variant_t` because, who knows, one abominates them (not that uncommon), or one doesn't trust the compiler to actually do a good job at keeping them alive, or one already uses other smart wrappers, or one really likes to explicitly call `SysFreeString` and `VariantClear`, then one specifies `raw_native_types`.

Comment: I figured as much but wasn't sure if there's any real benefit.  I would think you would want the wrappers since BSTR's are notorious for memory leaks.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, each `comsupp[w][d].lib`, which seem static libraries, takes at least 400KB, so you avoid that in your executable if you don't already link to it elsewhere.